# CSV resize columns depending on the content

Tags: php, csv, fwrite, export-to-csv

I wonder if it is possible to set the size of columns based on the content they contain.
I would like when you open the CSV once it has been directly generate columns are the right size.

For write in the CSV I have this code :

```
$csvFile = fopen(CSV_FILE, $writeMode);
            $searchStr = array(";");
            $replaceStr = array(",");
            foreach ($csvArray as $csvArrayRow) {
                fwrite($csvFile, iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252",str_replace($searchStr, $replaceStr, html_entity_decode($csvArrayRow["title"], ENT_HTML401 | ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")).";"));
                fwrite($csvFile, iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252",str_replace($searchStr, $replaceStr, html_entity_decode($csvArrayRow["author"], ENT_HTML401 | ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")).";"));
                fwrite($csvFile, $csvArrayRow["date"].";"."\n");
            }
            fclose($csvFile);

            echo json_encode(array(count($csvArray)));

            exit;
```

It is possible to add something to resize columns or is it somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSV files do not contain any information about column width at all, which is why even if you open a file, set the column width and then save it as a CSV file, the next time you open them it won't have saved the width you set it to. So no, you can't set the width of the column for when they open.

Comment: that's what I thought too, but as I metrized by far not all the technology for generating CSV I was not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably fill every field with spaces till it was a predetermined size. But I guess that it would still depend on where you are opening the CSV file. Anyway, I don't think it's considered a good practice to do this.

Comment: csv is generated, add an approximate number of space really is not a good practice and I'm not sure that even with space columns are resized. But thank you anyway.